# How to match substrings between two known points using preg_match_all()?

Tags: php, filepath, preg-match-all, regex-negation, character-class

I know that its easy to extract string between two slashes using `explode()` function in PHP. What if the string is like:

```
localhost/used_cars/search/mk_honda/md_city/mk_toyota
```

I want to extract string after `mk_` up until the slashes like: `honda` and `toyota`.

Here is my code:

```
$input = 'localhost/used_cars/search/mk_honda/md_city/mk_toyota';
preg_match('#/mk_([^/]*)/#', $input, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

The code is only extracting `honda` from `mk_honda` but why its not getting `toyota` from `mk_toyota`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're not using `preg_match_all`, second there is no `/` at the end of the second thing `toyota` so it doesn't match, remove it:

```
preg_match_all('#/mk_([^/]*)#', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```